# VirtualBox, Hyper-V and a Linux host

Tags: virtualbox, hyper-v

I created a Virtual Machine with Virtualbox - the host system is Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.2, the guest - Windows 8.1 Pro. I enabled all acceleration features in the VM settings.

To run the WP8 emulator one needs Hyper-V. But, to my surprise, the Windows guest claims that Hyper-V is not supported.

Is it possible to use Hyper-V on a Windows guest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is now possible to use Hyper-V on a Windows guest OS, but not with VirtualBox. This technology is referred to as nested virtualization.

You can vote up the feature request for VirtualBox [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032). Unfortunately, that request has been around for 6 years now, and the devs initially indicated that it would only be of "limited usefulness." With more and more SW relying on virtualization (Windows Mobile Emulation, Android Emulation, Vagrant, etc.), I would hope that it becomes a higher priority. It's still being actively commented on and requested as recently as 11/16/2015, but as of May 2015 the developers still have "different priorities."

As of the Windows 10 Fall Update (and the Windows Server 2016 previews), Hyper-V is now capable of nesting a Hyper-V hypervisor:

> Nested virtualization is running virtualization inside a virtualized
>   environment. In other words, nesting allows you to run the Hyper-V
>   server role inside a virtual machine.

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/nesting). The technology is still very new and appears to still be in preview.

The open source Xen hypervisor also claims support for nested virtualization:

> Nested virtualization is the ability to run a hypervisor inside of a
>   virtual machine. The hypervisor that runs on the real hardware is
>   called a level 0 or L0; the hypervisor that runs as a guest on L0 is
>   called level 1 or L1; a guest that runs on the L1 hypervisor is called
>   a level 2 or L2.

source: http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Nested_Virtualization_in_Xen

VMWare also has extensive support for multiple nesting scenarios in its commercial products:

> Hyper-V requires hardware-assisted virtualization, so it can only be
>   run under ESXi 5.0, Workstation 8, Player 4 or Fusion 4 (or later).
>   Hyper-V performs relatively poorly as a guest hypervisor under ESXi
>   5.0, but it performs reasonably well under Workstation 8, Player 4 or Fusion 4 (or later).   Under Workstation 9, Player 5 or Fusion 5, you
>   should set the guest OS type to "Hyper-V."

source: http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8970

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. Hyper-V features are for hosting virtual machines (VMs). As far as I know, you cannot host hardware-accelerated VMs from a VM. Kind of by definition, VMs are hosted from a host. If Linux is your host, Hyper-V is not the host.

(I guess it is possible to emulate an entire VM using software, without hardware-acceleration, but this makes the VM incredibly slow so I wouldn't recommend this. This is also not the way Hyper-V works.)

VM acceleration features allow you to use your hardware more effectively inside a VM, e.g. they might let a VM directly access a GPU. They will not, however, turn a guest into a (hardware accelerated) host.

When you install Windows 8 Pro directly on the machine, then you can add Hyper-V features to turn it into a host for VMs. I am not familiar with the WP8 emulator, but it sounds like it needs the current OS to be a Hyper-V host so that the WP8 emulator can run as a VM.

You will probably need either

- to install Windows 8.1 Pro directly on your hardware and add Hyper-V features to host VMs;
- to install Windows Hyper-V Server (which is free and downloadable from Microsoft's website);
- to install the full Windows Server with Hyper-V role (not free).

I expect that the WP8 emulator cannot be installed in a guest VM by making use of a Hyper-V host in this setup.

Installing the WP8 emulator on a Windows 8 or Windows Server host shouldn't be much of a problem. However, the free Hyper-V Server might not be a practical solution for your case (unless you can install the WP8 emulator on the Hyper-V Server, which may be tricky since that is, in a sense, a stripped down version of Windows Server Core).

If/when you choose to use Hyper-V as your hypervisor (host for VMs) then you can of course also run other VMs, e.g. to run Linux. VirtualBox is also available for Windows, but I don't know if that works alongside a Hyper-V installation. Perhaps you could run your existing VMs also on a Windows VirtualBox.

Finally, I have not done this myself, but it should be possible install a dual-boot system with Windows 8.1 and Linux, so that you can alternate between which hypervisor to use. To me this always seemed like a less preferable solution, since then you cannot always run all your VMs (i.e. you cannot run your Hyper-V VM when you've booted into the Linux hypervisor). I'd prefer to pick one and stick with it for all VMs on that machine.